# VBA run time Excel

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, invalid-argument

I'm using the below code Excel 2016 VBA & the sheet is saved on a shared drive on the network to be used by multi-users

I've merged cell from J1:M1, it works on my PC & on some PCs shows

> run-time error 5 : invalid procedure call or argument

taking into consideration that all users use the same excel 2016

```
Range("J1").value= left(application.username, instr(application.username,"@")-1
```

Answer (score 2):

most likely it fails for users where `application.username` doesn't contain a `@`

You can use a separate function that checks for the @-sign

```vb
Public Function getUserName() As String

If InStr(Application.UserName, "@") > 0 Then
    getUserName = Left(Application.UserName, InStr(Application.UserName, "@") - 1)
Else
    getUserName = Application.UserName
End If

End Function
```

and use it like this:

`Range("J1").value = getUserName`